# PDF is blank and damaged when downloading it from API using JavaScript and React JS

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, microservices

I am downloading a pdf file from API, but I am getting a blank PDF. I have tested the API endpoint and able to get the byte stream on the console and when I save it to File, it got saved and the file looks good. Getting the same response back to the front end using React and I could see the PDF byte stream in the response.
However, I could not see the content. It says the file is `damaged or corrupted` when I opened the downloaded PDF from my local.
I have looked at many examples and are following the same pattern, but I think I am missing something here.

My API Java endpoint definition looks like below

```
@GetMapping(value = "/fetchFile")   
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> fetchFile(@RequestParam final String key) {
        FileResponse response = myService.readFile(key);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                "attachment; filename=\"" + key.substring(key.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + "\"");
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().headers(httpHeaders).contentLength(response.getContentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(response.getContentType()))
                .body(response.getResponseBytes()));
    }
```

Frontend:

```
rounterFetchFile.js

router.get('/', (request, resp) => {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    baseURL: 'http://mybackend.apibase.url',
    responseType: 'blob',
    url: '/fetchFile',
    params: {
      fileKey: 'myfile.pdf'
    }    
  })
    .then(response => {      
      return resp.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
      return resp.status(error.response.status).end()
    })
})
```

in `myFileComoponent.js`
//a function that reads the response from rounterFetchFile.js

```
const getDocumentOnClick = async () => {
      
        try {
            var {data} = await pullMyPDF()
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/pdf" });
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "myFileName.pdf";
            link.click();                     
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

Here

```
var {data} = await pullMyPDF()
```

is returning the following content. I compared it with the result returned by the Postman, and it is the same. The generated file size is not empty from the react too. I am not able to find out where is it wrong
[image]

Below is the response from API endpoint for the fetchFile
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you convert the byte stream in React instead of fetching the PDF directly from the back-end (send out application/pdf)?

Comment: @Fullslack.dev, as per my knowledge, yes the PDF is sending application/pdf from the backend only in my example. The response type is byte[]. I tried with the Resource as response type from the API endpoint, it is still the same issue

Comment: https://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/download-pdf-file-using-spring-mvc-rest-controller

Comment: @Fullslack.dev, I checked the response headers, I got the same values what you have referenced in the link. Updated post with the response received in postman from API

Comment: Again: why is the return type of your ResponseEntity in Java a byte[] and not a InputStream? Then you also convert the byte[] to a blob and pass it around to finally trying to make a PDF out of it. Multiple conversions is bound to cause a error and a corrupted file in the end. Btw I don't consider React a back-end, for me that ends when you leave the Java code in this example.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, First I tried InputStream only, the issue is the same. Sorry I did not get your last point 'React is backend' , React is not my backend , it is java

Comment: Do you know how to read the input stream in the front code using javascript code/react? technicalkeeda.com is only an example of an endpoint from the backend

Comment: Try appending the link to your page before you trigger a click, e.g: `document.body.appendChild(link);`.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it with this:

- spa

  ```
           axios.post(
            'api-url',
            formData,
            {
              responseType: 'blob',
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/pdf'
            }
           })
           .then( response => {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
                this.setState({
                    filePath: url,
                    fileType: 'pdf',
                })
            })
           .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
           });
  ```
- api

  ```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
   {
       var request = HttpContext.Request;

       var pdfByteArray = await convertToPdfService.ConvertWordStreamToPdfByteArray(request.Form.Files[0], "application/msword");

       return File(pdfByteArray, "application/pdf");
   }
  ```

When the response type is a blob and accepted 'application / pdf' in the header, with that config the job is done ;) ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried these already, the issue still the same. can you please share how your api-end-point returns the response? I think it depends on it as well. Is it stream or byte[]? have you done any encoding?

Comment: Hi Mark, in my case I return the pdf file as a stream, not a byte[].

Comment: ok. thanks. how about the content-disposition. using an attachment or inline?

Comment: ok, thanks for the API code. so it's returning byteArray[] or stream. I am using java, so I can use it accordingly

Comment: I have used the same axios code to render pdf but got the error "TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
"

Comment: I was missing the responseType: 'blob' in the request. Thank you. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was to **send the bytes as base64** from the controller.

API:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync() {
    var documentBytes = await GetDocumentAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Ok(Convert.ToBase64String(documentBytes))
}
```

Front End:

```js
client.get(url, {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
    .then(response => {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + response.data;
        link.download = 'file.pdf';
        link.click();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

I hope this solves your problem.